# pygame rectangle moving back to its original position after every move

Tags: python

I'm making a game for a school assignment and every time the character moves, it moves back to its original position. I'm not particularly well versed in pygame but I've looked over time and time again and I can't really figure out what the problem is.

Any tips?

````
import math
import sys
import pygame

def game():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    purple = (127, 84, 253)

    running = True       
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                break
                running = False

        player_x = 12
        player_y = 12
        velocity = 10

        surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))    
        player = pygame.Rect(player_x,player_y,20,20)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:player.y-=50
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:player.x-=50
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:player.y+=50
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:player.x+=50
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:pygame.quit()
                
        

        pygame.display.flip()
        
        pygame.display.update()

        surface.fill((255, 255, 255))

        clock.tick(40)


    pygame.quit()


game()```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
        player_x = 12
        player_y = 12
        velocity = 10
```

Should be out of the while loop you are resetting them each frame which cause the problem